# Can you install a Python package via R - Reticulate

Tags: python, r, interface, reticulate

I am about to create a python interface in R with the package Reticulate. In order to access the python functions in R, the respective python packages need to be installed.

Two questions came to my mind:

1) If you use the reticulate package, does the Anaconda package need to be installed? Or is it sufficient to install the python packages only?

2) Is it possible to install python packages in R, similar to install.packages("r_package")?

Does anyone have experience with this Topic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. "Anaconda" isn't a package. Its a bundle of packages and other stuff. They may or may not exist on any given python installation. 2. Are you just asking how to install python packages? Like, using `pip`?

Comment: 1. I am wondering if I can install a single package, e.g. XLWings and then use it in R via Reticulate without having Anaconda installed on my Computer 2. Installing a package in R only requires "install.packages("r-package"). In my case I would like to install xlwings, but not via pip install xlwings, but directly in R. Is that possible?

Comment: If you have the `pip` module  in the python you are calling from R, you can use that to install python modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add a little bit of nuance to the previous answer.

Like @f0nzie said, Anaconda is not a package, but a *package manager*.  Ideally, you will create an environment using Anaconda to assist with your package management and version control.  The documentation for conda environments is [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/concepts.html#conda-environments).

Now, you can install python packages to your anaconda package in R.  That is possible using `reticulate::conda_install(envname, packages)`.  The documentation for `conda_install()` can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reticulate/versions/1.10/topics/conda-tools).

Answer (score 4):

1) The R package `reticulate` can work with the default python or with `Anaconda2` or `Anaconda3`. If you want Anaconda to work with R, you will have to install Anaconda first. Once installed, you call the `library(reticulate)`, and run `py_config()` or `reticulate::py_discover_config()`, that will give you the list of paths and environment used by the Python installation. Then, once you know the Python path, you add a line like this `use_python("/opt/miniconda2/bin/python")`, right after `library(reticulate)` and you are in business.

2) to install Python packages so R (or reticulate) can see them, you have to install them as regular Python packages from a terminal or console; not R. Example: `conda install numpy` to install numpy, or `conda install scipy` to install scipy, and so on.

I am just doing all this in a Docker container `rocker/rstudio`. It should be easier in a standard OS.

Here is step-by-step instructions: [rstudio reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a specific version of Python modules then place `==` after module name, e.g. the following will install specific versions of 3 modules using pip:

```r
reticulate::conda_install(c("PyMuPDF==1.14.20", "PyPDF2==1.26.0", "reportlab==3.5.23"),
                            envname = "myenv", pip = TRUE)
```